# how to check if all elements are equal with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have json data from curl like this:

```
[
   {
     "state": "foo",
   },
   {
     "state": "foo",
   },
   {
     "state": "foo",
   }
]
```

output of `curl uri | jq .[].state` would be

```
"foo"
"foo"
"foo"
```

How can I check with **jq** if all the "state" values are equal and use this **true** or **false** status next in my condition? in this example I would get **true** value.

but here

```
"foo"
"foo"
"bar"
```

should be **false**

Answer (score 1):

#### Warning: *highly inefficient*

1. Get all `.state` where value **is not** `foo`
2. Check if `length == 0`

```
jq 'map(select(.state != "foo")) | length == 0'
```

#### [Jq▷Play |~|  TRUE](https://jqplay.org/s/spnzpUAf4B)

#### [Jq▷Play |~| FALSE](https://jqplay.org/s/-N302xfGOB)

Answer (score 1):

It would be easy to come up with an inefficient solution, e.g. using `map` or `unique`, but it's also quite easy to use `all/2` to devise an efficient, generic solution.

Consider the following stream-oriented function:

```
# Return `true` if s is the empty stream
def allEquals(s):
  (first(s) // null) as $x | all(s; .==$x);
```

Using this, we can efficiently test for the equality of all the .state values in an array of objects as in the sample data, while ignoring other keys:

```
allEquals(.[].state)
```

### Footnote

Of course, if the objects in the array have only one key, as in the sample shown in the Q, one could simply write:

```
.[0] as $x | all(.[]; . == $x)
```

Thanks to jq's neat handling of edge cases, this works even if the input array is empty.

Comment: Can this be expanded to work if the objects would contains other keys than just 'state'?

Comment: seems your example lead me to this:
`[.[].state == ("foo") ] | all`

Comment: @TravErse - You've just found another way to use `map`.  That is, it's inefficient.

Comment: @peak, would you please explain - what do you mean by inefficiency?

Comment: @TravErse - The unnecessary consumption of computational resources (time-wise and/or space-wise). In the case of your solution, both.  In fact, if you analyze the computational requirements of your solution, you'll find it's generally worse than 0stone0's. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_efficiency

Answer (score -1):

this code `[.[].state == ("foo") ] | all` works as expected

Comment: This requires the construction of a new array of length N (where N is the length of the original array), and then potentially (in the worst case) the traversal of this new array in its entirety ...